# Geom_smooth - linear regression through x-axis intercept

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I would like to force a linear regression through a specific x-axis crossing point using "geom_smooth" in ggplot2:

```
geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

Intuitively, choosing an x-axis intercept, one would use the formula y = a * (x - b) + c.
Implementing this in the "formula" code as e.g. :

```
 geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x - 5)
```

Does not work.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use the `offset` function for the x-intercept that's already locked in. That's passed via the `method.args` argument of `geom_smooth`, since not all smoothing methods can use that argument.

You'll also need to specify the `orientation` argument to confirm that you've got an x-intercept, rather than the y-intercept.

I also specified the number of smoothing points to plot (`n`) and the offset repeats to match -- not sure if that's strictly necessary.

Some gymnastics to be sure, but hopefully it helps.

```r
library("tidyverse")
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(disp, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", 
              orientation = "y", 
              formula = y ~ x + 0, 
              color= "blue", 
              se = FALSE, 
              n = nrow(mtcars),
              method.args=list(offset=rep(100, nrow(mtcars))),
              fullrange = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits =c(0, 600)) 
#> Warning: Removed 5 rows containing missing values (geom_smooth).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure it is possible to do this just using geom_smooth. However, you could predict the regression outside of your ggplot2 call, using an offset to set the intercept required and plot it subsequently.

For example:

```
set.seed(1)

# Generate some data
x <- 1:10
y <- 3 + 2*x + rnorm(length(x), 0, 2)

# Simple regression
z_1 <- lm(y ~ x)
# Regression with no intercept
z_2 <- lm(y ~ x + 0)
# Regression with intercept at (0,3) - the 'true' intercept
z_3 <- lm(y ~ x + 0, offset=rep(3, length(x)))

# See the coefficients
coef(z_1)
#(Intercept)           x 
#   2.662353    2.109464 
coef(z_2)
#     x 
#2.4898 
coef(z_3)
#       x 
#1.775515 

# Combine into one dataframe
df <- cbind.data.frame(x,y,predict(z_1),predict(z_2), predict(z_3))

# Plot the three regression lines
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x,y)) +
             geom_line(aes(x,predict(z_1)), color = "red") +
             geom_line(aes(x,predict(z_2)), color = "blue") +
             geom_line(aes(x,predict(z_3)), color = "green") +
             scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,10)) +
             scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,30))
```

[image]